# CloudFoundry V3 API for Domains - Java Client

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

We are writing an `API` that would get list of all the domains available in a `cloudfoundry-foundation`. Our `API` internally uses [cf-java-client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) libraries to talk to our `cloudfoundry-foundation`

When we searched for the API Docs for listing all the domains, we ended-up [in this API Doc](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/10.1.0/domains_(deprecated)/list_all_domains_(deprecated).html) and understood that all V2 Domains API is **deprecated** and the suggestion over there is to use V3 Domains by [referring this API Document](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.74.0/index.html#list-domains)

Screen shot below that shows that `cf-java-client` is using deprecated APIs to get the domains

[image]

But I couldn't find any Java classes in `cf-java-client` that would help me retrieve the domains from `V3-API`

Can this be achieved in `cf-java-client` ? or as of now, I should use only `V2-Domains` ? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to skip `V2` Domain stuffs by getting `Domain` object directly from `DefaultCloudFoundryOperations`

*For Getting all the Domains*

```java
import org.cloudfoundry.operations.domains.Domain;

DefaultCloudFoundryOperations cfOps= .... ;

List<Domain> domainList = cfOps.domains().list().collectList().block();
```

*For Creating the Domain*

```java
public static void createADomain() {
        DefaultCloudFoundryOperations cfOps= .... ;
        CreateDomainRequest createDomainRequest = CreateDomainRequest.builder()
                .domain("arunsample.company.com")
                .organization(ORG_NAME)
                .build();

        cfOps.domains().create(createDomainRequest).block();

        System.out.println("Domain Created successfully .. ");
    }
```